# declaring a function to wait for a promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I have the following function:

```
function JSON_to_buffer(json) {
    let buff =  Buffer.from(json);
    if ( json.length < constants.min_draft_size_for_compression) {
        return buff;
    }
        return zlib.deflate(buff, (err, buffer) => {
            if (!err) {
                return buffer;
            } else {
                return BPromise.reject(new VError({
                    name: 'BufferError',
                }, err));
            }
        });
}
```

I want to be able to run this but have it wait if it goes to the unzip call. I'm currently calling this within a promise chain and it's going back to the chain without waiting for this and returns after the previous promise chain has completed.

Comment: You can chain a "then" to run after your promise: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Basic_Example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put that logic into a `Promise` along with an `async` function

```
function JSON_to_buffer(json) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let buff = Buffer.from(json);
        if (json.length < constants.min_draft_size_for_compression) {
            return resolve(buff);
        }

        zlib.deflate(buff, (err, buffer) => {
            if (!err) {
                resolve(buffer);
            } else {
                reject(err);
                /*return BPromise.reject(new VError({
                    name: 'BufferError',
                }, ));*/
            }
        });

    });

}

async function main() {
    try {
        let buffer = await JSON_to_buffer(myJSON);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: if I use await and my code returns at 'return buff;' would that cause issues

Comment: @Will you always need to call the function `resolve` in order to get the specific value from the function `JSON_to_buffer`

Comment: didn't use the await but did take your function rewrite and use it many thanks :)